# Trouble with Cucumber and URI::InvalidURIError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber

I am trying to start my cucumber tests. I get the error:

```
bad URI (absolute but no path): http:// (URI::InvalidURIError)
/home/de..........:common.rb:146:in 'split'
/home/de..........:common.rb:211:in 'parse'
/home/de..........:common.rb:747:in 'parse'
...
```

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue was because of http_proxy in ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks @user1067779! I too ran into this problem because I had a http_proxy bash variable set to an empty string. Unsetting it solved it.

Comment: I was getting this using Intellij's cucumber runner. I unset the http_proxy and restarted the IDE to get it working. Setting env vars inside IntelliJ was futile. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Might be the case of spaces in the url specified somewhere in your cucumber feature file, as explained here: http://www.practicalguile.com/2007/09/15/raising-uriinvalidurierror-from-a-perfectly-valid-uri/

Comment: What is the best way to check it? Is it possible to print it on console to see what url it is?

Comment: The full stacktrace could give an indication as to which line of the feature/code is causing this error. Look for lines related to the code of your app.

Comment: Thanks again. I know when the error happens. It happens in my first steps:

Comment: Given /^I am logged in$/ do
 visit user_signin_path

Comment: The user_signin_path is a route. Can you give me a advise for closer investigation?

Comment: Does `rake routes` show the right entry for `user_signin_path`? Are you able to go to the user sign in page from the browser? Just for the heck of it, try `visit(user_signin_path)` in the steps file, to make sure that line isn't adding any spaces.